# Real Time Google Map in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I have a google map that shows up on a page, with markers on each location with a different marker based on each locations status.

I want for when a location is updated: the map to be re-rendered for everyone who is viewing it. This means all the markers would update, so no user would be looking at old marker indicators.

How can I achieve this? I tried to use `render_Sync`, but apparently `render_sync` gem has to load an entire collection seperately. Meaning it tries to render the map as many times as locations there are, which sends too many requests to Google Maps and fails/breaks it.

Answer (score 1):

Your google map is initialized in your view via Javascript call. You just need to write method which make repeated calls to your controller or other REST server in some time intervals. After each successfull response you will update your markers positions.

Something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
var markers = [];
var once = true;
$(document).on('rails_admin.dom_ready', function() {
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {maxZoom: 20, zoom: 15}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        getMarker();
        window.setInterval(getMarker, 5000);
    });

});


    function getMarker() {
        $.post('/api/v1/get_position',
                {
                    uuid: '<%= @object.uuid %>'
                },
        function (data, status) {
            handler.removeMarkers(markers);
            markers = [];
            markers = handler.addMarkers([
                {
                    "lat": data.lat,
                    "lng": data.lng,
                    "infowindow": "<%= @object.name %>"
                }
            ]);
            if (once) {
                handler.fitMapToBounds();
                handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
                handler.map.centerOn({ lat: data.lat, lng: data.lng });
                once = false;
            }
            console.log(data);
        });
    };

</script>


<div style="width: 800px;">
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Action Cable to broadcast the coordinates to the UI, save them in some data attributes and poll them from your map script.

You can follow the steps below:

- Create a new channel. Lets call it 'locations':

  `rails g channel locations`
- Broadcast the latest coordinates as you receive them:

  `ActionCable.server.broadcast 'locations_channel', { latitude: 'NEW_LATITUDE', longitude: 'NEW_LONGITUDE' }`
- Once you receive the latest coordinates on the UI, you can set them as data attributes for your map `div` like this:
  `$('#map').data(data);`
  You can find the code snippet for this part in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/muaad/a4cccd20a82cc506332f695b67305c12)
- Poll the map `div`'s data attributes at a regular interval and update the marker's position with:
  `marker.setPosition(latlng)`

I have written [a step by step guide on Medium on how to do this](https://medium.com/@muaad/real-time-google-maps-integration-for-ruby-on-rails-with-action-cable-9dd1042ee163). You can take a look for more.

Comment: "In this section, I will be assuming that you have some external service that is sending you the latest location and you are saving this data at some action."
Which one do you recommend here, ive been looking for some time and I can see a good one.

Comment: @kenSanchez If you are asking about which service was sending me location info, I had some trackers connected to cars that were sending me their coordinates. I have no service to recommend.